# xml in asp read and write

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to read xml file in asp.net use c#  and also to write I tried this code

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("TestXml.xml")))

        { 

            reader.Read();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Response.Write( reader.Value.ToString());
                Response.Write("<br />");

            } 

        }
```

and the output is:

[image]

and the xml is

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <note>
      <to>Chayem</to>
      <from>Shaul</from>
      <heading>Way?</heading>
      <body>because</body>
      </note>
```

What do I do?  Thank you.

Comment: `</br>` would not be right; `<br/>`. Notice the placement of the `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlReader.Read()` always processes the next node in the document.  Note:  *node*, not *element*.  If you step through that code and examine each node, you'll see that while there are only six elements in the XML document, the `XmlReader` is processing eleven nodes.

This is because your XML document (like most) has text nodes containing whitespace characters between the elements.  Your code is writing a `<br/`> to the response every time the `XmlReader` encounters a node.  What you want is to write one out every time the `XmlReader` encounters an element with text content.

A way to do this is to simply only write out nodes that contain something other than whitespace, e.g.:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value.ToString().Trim())
{
   Response.Write(reader.Value.ToString())
   Response.Write("<br/>");
}
```

But why are you even using an `XmlReader`?  There are much easier ways to generate this output.  Load the XML into an `XDocument`, for instance, and you can produce the output like this:

```
Response.Write(string.Join("<br/>", doc.Descendants()
   .Where(x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value.ToString().Trim())
   .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
   .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that XmlReader reads also the `\n` parts of the XML.

Try to use something like this:

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Server.MapPath("feedback.xml")))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Value == "\n")
        {
            Response.Write("<br />");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(reader.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** You've said there were too many spaces between each line in the output. Considering XmlReader reads also the `\n` characters, using your method added extra empty lines in the result. My solution is to insert a `<br />` tag only when the reader encounters a new line.

Comment: Because, testing this code with a XML sample created with Visual Studio, the reader recognized only `\n`.

Comment: I did not understand please clarify

Comment: I've tried to be more specific in the edit. I hope now you'll understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Writing example:

```
public void WriteXml(List<string> filePaths, List<string> fileName)
        {
            //creating xml file
            XmlElement mainNode, descNode;
            XmlText pathText, nameText;

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            // Write down the XML declaration
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

            // Create the root element
            XmlElement rootNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ImageStore");
            xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
            xmlDoc.AppendChild(rootNode);

            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Count; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("first xml image "+i);
                // Create a new <Category> element and add it to the root node
                XmlElement parentNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Image");

                // Set attribute name and value!
                parentNode.SetAttribute("ID", "01");

                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.PrependChild(parentNode);

                // Create the required nodes
                mainNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("URL");
                descNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
                //XmlElement activeNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Active");

                // retrieve the text
                pathText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(filePaths[i]);
                nameText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(fileName[i]);
                XmlText activeText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode("true");

                // append the nodes to the parentNode without the value
                parentNode.AppendChild(mainNode);
                parentNode.AppendChild(descNode);
                parentNode.AppendChild(activeNode);

                // save the value of the fields into the nodes
                mainNode.AppendChild(pathText);
                descNode.AppendChild(nameText);
                activeNode.AppendChild(activeText);



            }//end of for loop

            // Save to the XML file. Checks if previous file exist
            if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/imageStore.xml"))
            {
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/imageStore.xml");
                xmlDoc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/imageStore.xml");
            }
            else
            {
                xmlDoc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/imageStore.xml");
            }

            //return true;
        }//end of writeXml
```

Reading example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("./config.xml");

            XmlNodeList configSet = doc.GetElementsByTagName("config");

            foreach (XmlNode node in configSet)
            {
                XmlElement conElement = (XmlElement)node;

                configData.Add("raw",conElement.GetElementsByTagName("raw")[0].InnerText);


                //Console.WriteLine(raw + " space " + store + " space " + achieve + " space " + filter);
            }
```

the xml file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigFile>
<config>
 <raw>./raw/</raw>
 <store>./images/</store>
 <achieve>./achieve/</achieve>
<filter>*.jpg;*.png;*.gif</filter>
</config>
</ConfigFile>
```

Hope this helps you